# Change Many2one domain based on selection field

Tags: odoo

I want to change M2O field domain based on the user selection from selection field:

```
  @api.onchange('search_by')
  def _get_partner(self):
        partners  = self.env['customer.regist'].search([('name','!=','New')])
        partner_list = []
        partner_list2 = []
        for rec in partners:
            partner_list.append(rec.name)
            partner_list2.append(rec.phone)
        res = {}
        if self.search_by == 'code':
            res['domain'] = {'search_value': [('name', 'in', partner_list)]}
        if self.search_by == 'phone':
            res['domain'] = {'search_value': [('phone', 'in', partner_list2)]}
        return res
```

but the domain not change and get the default domain from model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
@api.onchange('search_by')
def _get_partner(self):
    partners  = self.env['customer.regist'].search([('name','!=','New')])
    partner_list = []
    partner_list2 = []
    for rec in partners:
        if rec.name :
            partner_list.append(rec.name)
        if rec.phone:
            partner_list2.append(rec.phone)
    res = {}
    if self.search_by == 'code':
        res['domain'] = {'search_value': [('name', 'in', partner_list)]}
    if self.search_by == 'phone':
        res['domain'] = {'search_value': [('phone', 'in', partner_list2)]}
    return res
```

Make sure that the 'False' values are never added to the domain, since it might give invalid results

Comment: not work, phone domain return the name domain also

Answer (score 1):

Change your function like this.

```html
@api.onchange('search_by')
  def _get_partner(self):
        partners  = self.env['customer.regist'].search([('name','!=','New')])
        partner_list = []
        partner_list2 = []
        for rec in partners:
            partner_list.append(rec.name)
            partner_list2.append(rec.phone)
        res = {}
        if self.search_by == 'code':
            domain = {'search_value': [('name', 'in',     partner_list)]}
        return {'domain': domain}
        if self.search_by == 'phone':
            domain = {'search_value': [('phone', 'in', partner_list2)]}
        return {'domain': domain}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but not work, the name value return correctly but phone value return the same value of name

Comment: Try to print your partner_list2 value for knowing what's wrong in your phone

Comment: I print the list and the values of phone returned

Comment: I think work with name but not work with phone is impossible. Can you share more code or detail?

Comment: class CustomerRegist(models.Model):
    _name = "customer.regist"
    name = fields.Char('ID', readonly=True, default='New')
    phone = fields.Char(required=True, string='Phone' ,store=True)

Comment: search_by= fields.Selection([('code', 'ID Number'),
                              ('phone', 'Phone Number'),
                              ],  track_visibility='onchange', string='Search Customer By')
    search_value= fields.Many2one('customer.regist',store=True, string='Search Value')